# Can Kohanim who will bless the people start their journey to the duchan before Retzei?

Tags: halacha, minhag, birchas-kohanim

[Shulchan Oruch Mishnah Berurah 128 (8) [25]](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14164&st=&pgnum=5) implies that the Kohanim should go up to bless the people after the prayer leader has said "Retzei".

I see that many knowledgeable Kohanim start going up before Retzei.

I can understand that the Kohanim might walk after washing their hands to a place from where they can reach the "duchan" easily. But I do not understand why they do not start their final journey to the duchan at Retzei.

Please explain.

Comment: What do you mean by "their final journey"?  Do you mean climbing steps?  What difference, for example, between Kohanim who wash their hands outside and re-enter the Shul before Retzeh, and Kohanim who wash, return to their places, and then start to walk towards the Duchan? Just the fact that one took extra steps to return to his place?  They can't just stand around and clog the area where the other Kohanim are trying to wash.  They do have to take _some_ steps, so why not toward the Duchan?

Comment: What I have seen in multiple places is that the kohanim make sure to be in their place in the front *before* the chazzan starts "Retzei." I have even seen the chazzan pause before "Retzei" to make sure that all the kohanim had time to make it up there.

Comment: To echo @Isaac, I'm also under the impression that, if a Kohen is not in place and ready to ascend at Retzeh, he may not go up.

Comment: The halacha is talking about the last moments a Cohen has to be up there,once he finishes retzei he can't go up,but going early is not a problem.

Comment: @sam, that sounds like an answer, especially if you can source or argue for it. Care to post it as one?

Comment: @sam I agree with msh210. But the words used in the source I quote do not seem to support this meaning.